# Null space of the sum of two positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric positive semidefinite matrices.

Is it true that $\operatorname{Null}(A+B) = \operatorname{Null}(A) \cap \operatorname{Null}(B)$?

I think this is wrong, but cannot find a simple counterexample.

Comment: Since you can't think of a counterexample, have you put any thoughts into why it might be true or why your attempted counterexamples fail?

Comment: $||(A+B)x||^2 = ||Ax||^2 + 2 \text{Re}(Ax,Bx) + ||Bx||^2$.  Take it from there.

Comment: The product BA is not positive semi-definite, I do not see how this would help? @O.Peters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the answer is yes, it wasn't that hard in the end. Here is a detailed proof:

If $x \in Null{A} \cap Null{B}$
then it is trivial to see that $x \in Null{A+B}$.
If $x \in Null{A+B}$, then
\begin{equation}
0 = \langle (A+B)x,x \rangle = \langle Ax,x \rangle + \langle Bx,x \rangle,
\end{equation}

where by positive semi-definiteness we have $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle Bx,x \rangle \geq 0$.
The sum of nonnegative numbers being nonegative, we deduce that
\begin{equation}
\langle Ax,x \rangle=\langle Bx,x \rangle=0.
\end{equation}

Since $\langle Ax,x \rangle=0$, we deduce from the fact that $A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite that $Ax=0$.
Similarly, $Bx=0$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: Sorry about my unuseful suggestion above, but I have a problem with your claim "Since ⟨Ax,x⟩=0, we deduce from the fact that A is symmetric that Ax=0".  See, for example if $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ this is not true.  However, for symmetric positive semi-definite $A$ it's true, but I don't see anything less powerful than a spectral decomposition of $A$ to prove it.

Comment: You are correct, I was focused on the spectral decomposition (hence the symmetry) but the semi-definiteness is essential as well.

Comment: This was asked later... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173715/singular-matrix-and-positive-semidefiniteness