# Singular matrix and positive semidefiniteness

Tags: positive-semidefinite

Let $C_x$ be a psd matrix. If $b^TC_xb=0$, then why must $C_x$ be a singular matrix and how do you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume that when you say 'psd', $C_x$ is assumed to be symmetric.  Some people appear to consider the definition of 'psd' to apply to non-symmetric matrices as well, but Wikipedia says it's a term used only for symmetric matrices.
Second, I don't know if there's an elementary way of proving this without resorting to a spectral decomposition of $C_x$, or at least reconstructing some of the proof of a spectral decomposition.
Since $C_x$ is psd, it has a 'square root' - which means a psd matrix $S$ such that $S^2 = C_x$.  This is not a bypass of a spectral decomposition but is also proved via spectral decomposition. Now
$$0=b^\top C_x b = b^\top S^2 b = (Sb)^\top (Sb) = || Sb ||^2$$
So $Sb= 0 $ since $||Sb|| = 0$.  But then $C_x b = S^2 b=S(Sb)=0$.  So $b\in \operatorname{Ker} C_x$.

Comment: How does $b\in \operatorname{Ker} C_x$ prove singularity? Any reference?

Comment: First, the problem must state that $b\ne 0$.  For if $b=0$ then obviously $b^\top C_x b=0$ but $C_x$ doesn't have to be singular.  Now, if $b\ne 0$ and $C_x b=0$ then $C_x$ cannot be invertible, because the inverse would have to map $0$ to $b\ne 0$.  What's your definition of singularity?

Comment: Now I understand your point. thanks.